# Replacement needed for eventdelete function to delete google calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to delete selected calendar events but eventdelete function is now void in new scripts.

I have google script attached to a google spreadsheet which contains All Day event details. Collaborators use menus run the script to create or delete events in a google calendar.
The script loops through and selects the relevant events including its stored google calendar EventID and deletes or creates it in the google calendar. This all works fine.

I created a new google user account, new Google Calendar and new spreadsheet in a new Drive.
Having copied the Script to the new Sheet adjusting the CalendarID etc. it fails..
The EventDelete is now a Void function The error message is `TypeError: CalendarApp.deleteEventSeries is not a function`. Checking the list the function `deleteEventSeries` is now Void.
I have tested code and am able to edit description so the code is working as expected but I cannot find a function/method for deleting a google calendar event in the Calendar.

```
function DeleteCalendarEvents() {
    var CalID = "myUserName@gmail.com" 
    var cal =CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalID);
    // I have removed code which loops each row in a google spreadsheet
    //   and selects events marked delete grabbing its stored eventID. 

    {     
    var EventID = ("The event ID eg scrambledLettersNumbers@google.com");                                          
    var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(EventID);
    CalendarApp.deleteEventSeries();
    } 
}
```

Comment: var EventID = “put actual event I’d here”;

Comment: Sorry. not explained properly. I have edited the question. Assuming the eventID includes the @google.com part of the variable.

Comment: `event.deleteEventSeries()`

Comment: Event.deleteEventSeries() is also void

Comment: What do you means by `void`

Comment: In Google Apps Script References  Class CalendarEvent. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
The return type is Void If I use either eventdelete or eventdeleteseries code it will return 'not a function'.  
This errors in the New user account. but not in my 3 yr old account.

Comment: What else would it return? It's just deleting an event.  It certainly isn't going to return the event.  What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: [20-04-20 00:34:37:531 PDT] TypeError: CalendarApp.deleteEventSeries is not a function  at DeleteCalendarEvents(xxStackExample:10:25)
I think eventdelete and eventdelete have been deprecated.

Comment: I wrote Event.eventDeleteSeries() not CalendarApp.deleteEventSeries. The fact that it returns a void is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing some fundamentals of OOP. 
Is normal that your code is failing because the class CalendarApp has no function called `deleteEventSeries()`. You could try to find in [the reference for the class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app).

What you want to delete is actually the object that you have retrieved by invoking the method [`getEventSeriesById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventseriesbyidicalid) in the `Calendar` object which type is `CalendarEventSeries`.

So to delete that *Event series* you will need to indeed call the method [`deleteEventSeries()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series#deleteEventSeries()) but you need to use [`CalendarEventSeries`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series) object not `CalendarApp`.

```
function DeleteCalendarEvents() {
    var CalID = "myUserName@gmail.com" 
    var cal =CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalID);

    var eventSeriesID = "<Id of the event Series>";                                          
    var eventSeries = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventSeriesID);
    eventSeries.deleteEventSeries();

}
```

---

The functions are not deprecated as you have suggest in the comments. The returning type being `void` just means that the function will not return any variable which make sense because you have just deleted the event.

```
var a = eventSeries.deleteEventSeries();

>>> a == null // True
```

Comment: Raserhin. Thank you so much. Not sure how I changed that from the previous version. and for clarifying the Class issue.

Comment: Did this solved your issue? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so other people having the same issue may benefit it from.